# Ckeditor's Link Dialog incomplete?

Tags: ckeditor, xpages

In an Xpage running on Domino 9.0.1 I'm using a rich text control with some custom toolbar configuration using the control's "attr" property as it is described here: https://frostillic.us/f.nsf/posts/quick-and-dirty-ckeditor-toolbar-setup-for-xpages

I added the **link** toolbar template using

```
<xp:this.attrs>
    <xp:attr name="toolbar">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[[["Link", "Unlink", "Anchor"]]]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:attr>
</xp:this.attrs>
```

All three buttons are displayed fine, esp. I'm able to define an anchor link target.

But trying to reference the anchor target I find that the Link dialog is somewhat incomplete as I can't define my link to use a relative target on the same page. I tried entering a reference in the dialog's URL field as `#myAnchorId`, but that results in a link looking like this:

`<a href="http://#myAnchorId">...</a>`.

Here's an image of the dialog that pops up from my Xpage when I hit the "URL link" button:

[image]

And this is what the dialog looks like that I can test from the [CKEditor Samples page](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/plugins/toolbar/toolbar.html):

[image]

I'm aware that the samples page uses CKEditor V 4, so the dialog is somewhat different, but even V 3.6 should be able to reference anchor links using the dialog.

I already looked up on the installed ckeditor's version; \DominoData\domino\html\ckeditor\version.txt says:

```
cke_version=3.6.6.2
cke_revision=20130606-1534
```

Question is: what's missing here? Do I have to somehow modify the dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh my, finally got it to work; @IBM: this feature truly could use some proper documentation! I'll mark this answer as a community wiki.

Indeed a different dialog is used here, which btw appears to apply to all the dialogs in use with Domino's CKEditor implementation. The trick in my case is to use one of the custom toolbar items instead of the standard one; up to now I found three of those customized items:

- use `MenuLink` instead of the standard `Link` item; this item
  consists of two sub items ('URL Link' and 'Anchor Link'), each calling its own dialog version; the resulting toolbar definition then looks like this: `['MenuLink', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']`

[image]

- use `MenuPaste` instead of the standard `Paste` item; again, this
  item consists of two sub items ('Paste' and 'Paste as text'), again
  each calling its own dialog version

[image]

- use LotusSpellChecker to add IBM's own spell checking feature, where CKE's standard spell checker isn't working

I found hints to those three custom items inside my local \DominoData\domino\html\ckeditor\config.js. Don't know if those are all custom items available to day.

EDIT:

[IBM's Domino Designer Xpages User Guide](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/domino/designer/9_0_1/xp_user_guide/en_US/DominoDesignerXPagesUserGuide.html#wpd_controls_cref_inputrichtext) mentions another means of customizing the toolbar; the section unfortunately is incorrect in describing the options for the toolbarType attribute: be aware that all named types must start with capital letters, e.g. `Basic`, `Slim`, `Medium`, `Large`, `Full`, while the also mentioned *Lite* type isn't working at all; mistyping or using a non-existing value results in the editor not being displayed at all.

Comment: Just a note on the incorrect info in the xpages user guide you linked. Thanks for highlighting that. That will be fixed in 9.0.2 documentation. Unfortunately I'm told it cannot be corrected in the 9.0.1 documentation.

However, I've added a comment on the wiki to highlight the error: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Domino+Designer+9.0.1+User+Guide#action=openDocument&res_title=inputRichText_Rich_Text_dd901ug&content=pdcontent&sa=true

Comment: @Brian: thanks. I commented on that inside the wiki itself, as one of the examples there still shows a mistyped value ("full" instead of "Full")

Comment: In my testing Full, Medium & Large were not case-sensitive, but probably best to keep any chosen value with a capital to be safe, if you ran into problems there too

Answer (score 1):

The link dialog that you're using is not the default one, so you should check how to modify it or replace it with the default one.

Comment: I was somewhat afraid that would be the case. Unfortunately, this Version of ckeditor is included with the Server. So this case might be different from Standard cke implementations. Thanks anyways